# Passing in the database name to an SSRS report at runtime using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, reporting-services, datasource

I have an angular application that connects to a Report Server to view SSRS Reports.  The application uses a file path that is stored in a database to identify the report.  This is an example of the file path:

`http://<serverName>/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReportFolder%2fPatientReport`

I need to add a second data source to that this report can connect to a different database.  Currently, this report is hard-coded to 1 database.  But I read that I can create a second data source and dynamically link to another database.

Can I pass the name of the database in this file path and then use this database name to select the correct data source?

**UPDATE**
I found instructions to parameterize the database name.  I create a database on the server that all of the databases are stored and it has 1 table that contains the database names.  I create a data source to retrieve these names and created a parameter of 'DatabaseName' that will be the input from the user (hopefully I will be able to add this name to the file path string as a parameter so the user does not have to select it.)
So in the report I have a data source that returns a list of databases and a dynamic data source that uses this expression in the connection string to add the database name:

However, I have to connect this data source to the data set.  When I run it, 
`="Data Source=<server Name>;Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!DatabaseName.Value`

I try using this dynamic data source with the data set and I can't save the dataset because of the error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is this because I need to add the Database parameter to the query?
If so, is there any way to get around that?  Like be able to add:
USE @DatabaseName to the top of the query?

**UPDATE**
I got a basic report to display with optional databases.
Now, I just have to send the database name as a parameter into the report string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...in case this can help someone else.
In the report, I created a parameter, DatabaseName.
I also added an **embedded** data source. At first not dynamic but hard-coded.
The dataset also has to be embedded into the report and linked to the newly created data source.
Run the query and when successful. Save the report!
(What I found was the query has to be successfully run in order to save the report.  You cannot successfully run a query with a dynamic data source.)

Once the report has been saved, now change the data source to dynamic.  Open it and create an expression like this:

```
="Data Source=<server Name>;Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

Now, save and close the report.  You can't run it anymore from the server because it does not have a data source.

I ran it from my application using an URL with the DatabaseName as a parameter:

> http://serverName/ReportServer?%2fInitialFolderName%2fReportFolderName%2fReportName&rs:Command=Render&DatabaseName=Wrh1

In the above example the parameter, DatabaseName is set to Wrh1
The folder path is InitialFolderName/ReportFolderName/ReportName